# Resizing image in pytorch to match the dimensions of the model does not work

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torch

I get a **dimension mismatch error** when I run the predictor on the model, even though training, validation and testing work. I suppose this means there is a problem in image processing in the predictor model.

```
class Predictor(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, model, class_names, mean, std):
        super().__init__()

        self.model = model.eval()
        self.class_names = class_names
        
        self.transforms = nn.Sequential( # --- THIS MIGHT BE THE PROBLEM
            T.Resize([256, ]),
            T.CenterCrop(224),
            T.ConvertImageDtype(torch.float),
            T.Normalize(mean.tolist(), std.tolist())
        )

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Apply transforms --- THIS MIGHT BE THE PROBLEM TOO
            x  = self.transforms(x)

            # Get the logits
            x  = self.model(x)

            # Apply softmax
            x  = F.softmax(x, dim=1)

            return x
```

I tried hardcoding the dimensions of the input neurons of `model` class, it did work for a couple seconds then I got another dimension mismatch.

For example, at training, the model's input neurons were `128*7*7`, and then I hardcoded that to `57600` as this was the dimension of the input that raised the error. It did work for like 26 images during predicting but then it raised another dimension mismatch error with another dimension of `51200`.

**This indeed means that the image that are passed to the model are of inconsistent dimensions!**

**This also means that `self.transforms(...)` does not work because if it did, there wouldn't have been a dimension mismatch**

Comment: Have you done your sanity tests to make sure that the resizing function isnt working? I.e find the input image that breaks your code then debug from there.

Comment: Check what dimension the image is after the transform (this could be done simply by adding a print statement, for example).

Comment: Will try doing that and I will update the question asap

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the error by forcing the data plugged into the model to be transformed using a hardcoded `T.Compose([..., T.CenterCrop(224), ...])` to ensure the images themselves are plugged into the model cropped-ready.

But, I still do not understand why the following does not resolve that error

```
self.transforms = nn.Sequential(T.Resize([256, ]),
                                T.CenterCrop(224),
                                T.ConvertImageDtype(torch.float),
                                T.Normalize(mean.tolist(), std.tolist()))
```

Calling the model itself with `224*224` eliminates the error, but the model does not accept any other dimension as it raises a dimensionality error